# Public/private moethod declaration-only on ES6 classes with babel

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, private-methods, public-method, es6-class

I'm using Babel with default `es2015` preset to convert ES6 JS code. Since I'm working in another project with TypeScript, I've come to appreciate the publi/private annotation on methods.

I'd like to use the same annotation in JS code. Even if it won't actually make methods on the exported object private, I find it useful to know quickly if a method is used by other classes, or not.

Is there a Babel plugin or other means to strip away all public/private declarations, so I can use it in my code? even without namespace checking that would still be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a current [proposal for "Private Fields"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields) that is [in the process](https://github.com/babel/babylon/pull/260) of being implemented, but it not part of Babel yet. In the next month or two I'd expect it to be available.